# PHP Отсортировать многомерный массив по одинаковым значениям

Tags: php, массивы

Ломаю голову уже пару часов, я понимаю как можно отсортировать массив функциями что сделает код большим, и мне интересно, возможно есть какая то встроенная функция по сортировке массива по значению, чтоб если значения одинаковые, то он сортировал их в каждую ячейку, например есть такой массив:

```
[
    0 => [
        "name" => "One",
        "date" => "04.08.2023"
    ],
    1 => [
        "name" => "Two",
        "date" => "03.08.2023"
    ],
    2 => [
        "name" => "Three",
        "date" => "04.08.2023"
    ]
]
```

И я хочу чтоб сортировка была по значению "date" и на выходе получать такой вариант:

```
[
    "04.08.2023" => [
        0 => [
            "name" => "One",
            "date" => "04.08.2023"
        ], 
        1 => [
            "name" => "Three",
            "date" => "04.08.2023"
        ]
    ],
    "03.08.2023" => [
        1 => [
            "name" => "Two",
            "date" => "03.08.2023"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Нет такой функции, напиши свою.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это уже не сортировка, а трансформация, и под такие пишут свой код, определяющий суть перемен-трансформаций. Вам нужно пройтись по массиву, создать список с ключом по дате, а затем его отсортировать;

```
<?php
 
 $Initial = [
    0 => [
        "name" => "One",
        "date" => "04.08.2023"
    ],
    1 => [
        "name" => "Two",
        "date" => "03.08.2023"
    ],
    2 => [
        "name" => "Three",
        "date" => "04.08.2023"
    ]
];

$DataByDate = [];
foreach($Initial as $SubArray) {
    $DataByDate[$SubArray["date"]][] = $SubArray;
}

uksort($DataByDate, function($Left, $Right) {
    date_parse($Left) <=> date_parse($Right);
});

var_dump($DataByDate);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, примерно так я и сделал, но думал возможно есть подходящая под данную задачу функция в самом PHP, но по всей видимости нету, но все равно спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без подмены ключей:

```
<?php
$someArray =
    [
        0 => [
            "name" => "One",
            "date" => "04.08.2023"
        ],
        1 => [
            "name" => "Two",
            "date" => "03.08.2023"
        ],
        2 => [
            "name" => "Three",
            "date" => "04.08.2023"
        ]
    ];

$date  = array_column($someArray, 'date');
array_multisort($date, SORT_DESC, $someArray);

var_dump($someArray);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "One"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "04.08.2023"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Three"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "04.08.2023"
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "Two"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "03.08.2023"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но это немного не то, что мне нужно. Мне необходимо чтоб под каждую дату создавался отдельный ключ, в который будут входить все значения с этой датой